# If $a^{2k}=a$ for all elements of a ring then $a= -a$ for all $a$

Tags: ring-theory

If there is a positive even integer $n$ such that $a^n= a$ for all elements of a ring R then how to prove that $a+a=0$ for all $a$ in R. For Boolean ring, it is easy. But how to prove for $n>2$.

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^{2k}=1$ for all $k$.

Comment: $-a=(-a)^{2n}=(-1)^{2n}a^{2n}=a^{2n}=a$